# Dirac Delta Properties

Tags: dirac-delta

From [Mathworld](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/DeltaFunction.html), for example, we have the following properties of the Dirac delta:

$x^n\delta^{(n)}(x)=(-1)^n\, n! \, \delta(x)$

$x^2 \, \delta'(x)=0$

So, if $f(x)$ is $C^\infty(R)$, is it correct to guess that, from its Taylor expansion:

$f(x) \, \delta''(x-a)=f(a)\delta''(x-a)-f'(a)\delta'(x-a)+f''(a)\delta(x-a)$?

Comment: It is important to realize that all the properties of the $\delta$-function (and its derivatives) are obtained when one multiplies it by a test-function $f(x)$ and integrates from $-\infty$ to $+\infty$. The results you cite are therefore merely a sort of short-hand notation. They have been found by partial integration. That is also what you should do, and then things become fairly obvious. Certainly you should not "guess" the result !!!

Comment: I can tell you the result for the left hand side. If we perform partial integration twice in succession (as described above), we get: $f(x) \delta''(x-a)$ = $-f'(x) \delta'(x-a)$ = $f''(x) \delta(x-a)$.

Comment: Having said that, it is certainly permitted to expand the test-function $f(x)$ in a Taylor-series around $x=a$ and then to apply partial integration to each term. Thus I can confirm the correctness of the OP's expansion. [There is only a minor error in the second term on the RHS; the argument should be $x-a$ instead of $x$.]

Comment: While the "bottom line" is as @M.Wind says, that $x^2$ times a distribution $u$ really means $(x^2 u)(f)=u(x^2f)$ for test function $f$, this very thing does make sense of "multiplication of distributions by smooth functions". That is, those left-hand sides really _do_ have sense as distributions, as does the right-hand side... but using the argument "x" potentially confuses things, yes! Might be better to write just "$f$" rather than $f(x)$, and $\delta_a$ rather than $\delta(x-a)$. The usual notation for $x\to x^2$ as being just "$x^2$" may be inescapable...

Comment: The OP should keep in mind that while his expansion is okay, the first and second term on the RHS do not contribute anything !